# VBA - Access 2010 - Can't display total minutes in DD:HH:MM format if over 2 days

Tags: ms-access, time, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to convert total minutes to a DD:HH:MM format in VBA for Access 2010. HH:MM is straightforward, and I was able to resolve a total time over 24 hours like this:

```
If total / 1440 > 1 Then
    tbTimeTotal.Value = "1:" & Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
Else
    tbTimeTotal.Value = Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
End If
```

but the solutions I've tried for accommodating over 48 hours did not work:

First Try:

```
If total / 2880 > 2 Then
    tbTimeTotal.Value = "2:" & Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
ElseIf total / 1440 > 1 And total / 2880 < 2 Then
    tbTimeTotal.Value = "1:" & Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
Else
    tbTimeTotal.Value = Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
End If
```

Second Try:

```
If total > 2880 Then
    tbTimeTotal.Value = "2:" & Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
ElseIf total > 1440 And total < 2880 Then
    tbTimeTotal.Value = "1:" & Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
Else
    tbTimeTotal.Value = Format(total / 60 / 24, "hh:nn")
End If
```

Suggestions? Is there a more elegant approach I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateAdd` to add your total minutes to day 0 which will give you a Date/Time value.  You can then use date & time and other standard VBA functions with that value to create your custom time format.

Here are some examples based on the function below:

```vb
? CustomTimeFormat(720)
12:00
? CustomTimeFormat(790)
13:10
? CustomTimeFormat(1510)
1:01:10
? CustomTimeFormat(2955)
2:01:15
```

Notice you needn't code up all those math operations from your question because the VBA functions handle those details automagically.

```vb
Public Function CustomTimeFormat(ByVal pMinutes As Long) As String
    Dim lngDays As Long
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim dteEquivalent As Date
    dteEquivalent = DateAdd("n", pMinutes, 0)
    lngDays = CLng(DateValue(dteEquivalent))
    strTime = Format(dteEquivalent, "hh:nn")
    strOutput = vbNullString
    If lngDays > 0 Then
        strOutput = lngDays & ":"
    End If
    strOutput = strOutput & strTime
    CustomTimeFormat = strOutput
End Function
```